# Replacing array element with its negation in java

Tags: java, arrays

VERY new to java (first class of the intro course) and am having some trouble with writing a function that replaces each element in an array with the same integer but negative. I wrote this code:

```
int negation(int[] x) {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        if (x[i] != 0)
            x[i] = -x[i];
    }

    return x;
}
```

but when executing it get the error

> Expression has type int[], but an expression of type int was expected

on line 6. Not sure what this means exactly as I thought putting 'int[] x' made sure an array was expected, but apparently that isn't enough. Do I need to declare x as an array anywhere else?

Comment: Your method should return `int[]`, not `int`.

Comment: To be fair, you don't even need to return anything. An array is a reference object, you're modifying the very array you're passing to the method.

Answer (score 4):

You're returning `x` which is of type `int[]` but your method is declared as returning `int`.

Declaring your method as returning `int[]` by changing it to `int[] negation(int[] x)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
int[] negation(int[] x)
```

Returning just `x` should have the matching returning type in the function declaration.

If you `return x[0]` for example it would match the function declaration.